# Kendo ui template is not working with html encoded symbols

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-template

I have a template like that

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="email-view-template">
    <div>#=email_subject#</div>
    <div>#=email_body#</div>
</script>
```

The values comes from database(email_subject and email_body). Because of email_body kendo template is not working. email_body can have some encoded symbols (like `&#39;`)

Normally if I use # character in template i escape like `\\#` . but email_body comes from database.

How can I solve this problem?

**Example email_body which is comes from database**

```
&lt;p&gt;http://www.revula.com/tto/admin/event/show/id/3&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Linkte detayları verilen etkinliğe katılmak isteyen t&amp;uuml;m personelin bilgisi i&amp;ccedil;in &amp;Ouml;zyeğin &amp;Uuml;niversitesinden aldığım aşağıdaki mesajı paylaşıyorum.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;div style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;"&gt;Ekrem Bey Merhaba,&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;"&gt;&lt;br clear="none" /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="yui_3_16_0_1_1418222798054_35228" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;"&gt;Telefonda da bahsettiğim gibi eğitim verimliliğini arttırabilmek i&amp;ccedil;in aşağıda linkini paylaştığım anketi ekip arkadaşlarınıza, eğitim &amp;ouml;ncesi tamamlanması doğrultusunda iletebilirseniz &amp;ccedil;ok seviniriz.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;"&gt;&lt;br clear="none" /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="yui_3_16_0_1_1418222798054_35230" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;"&gt;&lt;a href="https://tr.surveymonkey.com/s/TargetEgitimi" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1418222798054_35229" rel="nofollow" shape="rect" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;background-color:transparent;color:purple;outline:none;" target="_blank"&gt;https://tr.surveymonkey.com/s/TargetEgitimi&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;"&gt;&lt;br clear="none" /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;"&gt;&lt;br clear="none" /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="yui_3_16_0_1_1418222798054_35216" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;"&gt;İyi &amp;ccedil;alışmalar,&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;"&gt;Gizem Asker/&amp;Ouml;z&amp;Uuml;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using jQuery for decoding it. You can do it by:

```
$("<div/>").html(subject).text()
```

This uses jQuery by appending it to the a `div` element but since it is not part of your page this is not a problem and then get `text` for it.

Following a snippet showing this approach

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var msg = "&lt;p&gt;http://www.revula.com/tto/admin/event/show/id/3&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Linkte detayları verilen etkinliğe katılmak isteyen t&amp;uuml;m personelin bilgisi i&amp;ccedil;in &amp;Ouml;zyeğin &amp;Uuml;niversitesinden aldığım aşağıdaki mesajı paylaşıyorum.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;div style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;'&gt;Ekrem Bey Merhaba,&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;'&gt;&lt;br clear='none' /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id='yui_3_16_0_1_1418222798054_35228' style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;'&gt;Telefonda da bahsettiğim gibi eğitim verimliliğini arttırabilmek i&amp;ccedil;in aşağıda linkini paylaştığım anketi ekip arkadaşlarınıza, eğitim &amp;ouml;ncesi tamamlanması doğrultusunda iletebilirseniz &amp;ccedil;ok seviniriz.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;'&gt;&lt;br clear='none' /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id='yui_3_16_0_1_1418222798054_35230' style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;'&gt;&lt;a href='https://tr.surveymonkey.com/s/TargetEgitimi' id='yui_3_16_0_1_1418222798054_35229' rel='nofollow' shape='rect' style='margin:0px;padding:0px;background-color:transparent;color:purple;outline:none;' target='_blank'&gt;https://tr.surveymonkey.com/s/TargetEgitimi&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;'&gt;&lt;br clear='none' /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;'&gt;&lt;br clear='none' /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id='yui_3_16_0_1_1418222798054_35216' style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;'&gt;İyi &amp;ccedil;alışmalar,&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style='font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;background-color:#ffffff;'&gt;Gizem Asker/&amp;Ouml;z&amp;Uuml;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;";
  var decoded = $("<div/>").html(msg).text();
  
  console.log("decoded", decoded);
  var model = kendo.observable({
    email_subject : "This is the subject",
    email_body : decoded
  });

  var tmpl = kendo.template($("#template").html());
  $("#tgt_template").html(tmpl(model));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
  <div>
   <div>Subject: #=email_subject#</div>
    <div>#=email_body#</div>
  </div>
</script>


<div id="tgt_template"></div>
```

Comment: i also tried #: ... # but it did not work. I put exampla email_body data

Comment: Check my new answer above